# Receive notification when something new happens on server side

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm building this POS with the format of a web application. I have an issue though. I want to notify the waiter that there is a new order ready to go. I made some notification buttons menu style but i'm not really sure how to notify from the server side the client that there is a new one.

My options as i saw it is AJAX function that calls a php file every so and updates the div with the current active orders or w/e.

I would also like to know what other options i may have?
How can i push notifications from the server or is there somehow that i can
avoid doing AJAX requests to the server every say X seconds?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe try using websockets?

Comment: You should read something about `comet` or may check this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899523/push-notification-to-the-client-browser] (Push notification)